# как кешировать данные с webView используя NSURLProtocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, кэширование, uiwebview

как кешировать данные с webView используя NSURLProtocol? У меня есть URL, я хочу кешировать данные ну чтобы в дальнейшем переход на сайт можно было в офлайн режиме.

Answer (score 0):

вот должно хватить:

```
//кеш и размер кеша
NSURLCache* cache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
[cache setMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024];
[cache setDiskCapacity:512*1024];

//урл и запрос
NSURL *webUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:webUrl
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                          timeoutInterval:20.0];
// NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad - берет данные из кеша если их нет то грузит запрос
```